# How to use a request field to save new a variable with that value?

Tags: php, database, laravel

So, I have a function that creates me alerts based on changes made on a profile.And I need to have customizable alerts for every field, like `name`, `city`, `email` etc.Now, I need to make this working and I also need to show me an alert like ... User x changed his `name` to y, or User z changed his `email` to w.

**Here is my controller**

```php
public function generalinfo(Request $request)
{
    if ( $user = Sentinel::getUser() ) {
        if ( $user->inRole('individuals') ) {
            $data = $this->data;
            $id = $user->id;
            $user = User::findOrfail($id);
            $generalinfo = User::firstOrNew(array('email' => $user->email ));
            $dob = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->get('dob')));
            $generalinfo->name = $request['name'];
            $generalinfo->city = $request['city'];
            $generalinfo->address = $request['address'];
            $generalinfo->email = $request['email'];
            $generalinfo->website1 = $request['website1'];
            $generalinfo->website2 = $request['website2'];
            $generalinfo->website3 = $request['website3'];

            $generalinfo->save();

            $feed = \App\Feed::create([
                'user_id'  => $id,
                'feed_url' => $request['rss'],
                'active'   => 1
            ]);

            $generalinfo = User::find($id);
            $generalinfo->name = 'NewName';
            // other $user changes

            foreach ($generalinfo->getDirty() as $key => $attribute) {
                $log = \App\Log::create([
                    'user_id'         => $id,
                    'log'             => " {$key} changed to {$user->user}.",
                    'date'            => time(),
                    'type'            => 'profile_updates',
                    'formatted_date'  => date_format(date_create(date('Y-m-d')),"F dS, Y"),
                    'action_user_id'  => $id,
                    'action_name'     => $user->name,
                    'action_username' => $user->username,
                    'profile_picture' => $user->profile_picture,
                ]);
            }
            $generalinfo->save();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my problem :  `$generalinfo->name = 'NewName';` .I need to get the new value from database from `$user->name`. The problem is, I tried to use this : `$generalinfo->name = $request['name'];` but with no effect.

Comment: seems like you need observer or event

Comment: Hey, I'm using laravel 5.2 and I can't use observer here:(

Comment: then you can try presave user data into some variabe before you making changes, then compare datas and log changes if they appear